Remove markers both with or without a leading comment character
I use Vim with marker folding for my work and the presence of all the fold markers annoys my colleagues, so I want a quick and easy way to cleanly remove them all from my files. Closing markers are easy, as I make sure they are always on their own line, preceded by varying amount of whitespace, so
:%s/^\s*# }}}\n//g

works fine.
Opening markers are a bit more of a problem as they can take one of two forms, either at the end of a comment (eg # IMPORTS {{{) or at the end of a block definition (eg def fn():  # {{{). I can deal with these two individually with
:%s/ {{{//g
:%s/  # {{{/g

but when I try to combine the two, I cannot get it to work. I have tried
:%s/( |  # ){{{)\\g
:%s/(  # {{{| {{{)\\g

both with and without an initial '^.*' before the parentheses but it didn't work (yes, I know that would have deleted the entire line, but I was hoping it would at least point me in the right direction). I've even tried escaping the various # and { characters out of sheer desperation, not expecting that to work since they don't need escaping in the individual substitutions, but regardless of what I try, all I get is a 'pattern not found' error. I've tried Googling, with no luck - all the answers I've found seem to say I'm doing it right, but I'm obviously misunderstanding them
It's not a major hassle having to use three instructions, especially as I plan to put this into a function, but I just want to know, what is the correct method of searching for and deleting either of the two patterns in one go?

I took the liberty of making your title more specific. Feel free to [edit] and improve further. Also: "the presence of all the fold markers annoys my colleagues, so I want a quick and easy way to cleanly remove them all from my files" :s/files/workplace/ :-)

You're not properly escaping your special characters.
You should either escape parentheses and the pipe or use very magic mode but then you'd have to escape the curly braces.
See :help /magic.

Escape parens and pipe
:%s/\(\|#\) {{{//


Use very magic mode
:%s/\v(|#)\s*\{\{\{//


Or just forget about the OR operator in favor of the \? (zero or one) quantifier. I threw in some \s* to also match any number of white space.
:%s/\s*\(#\s*\)\?{{{//



In general, :help pattern is recommended reading.
One more thing, if it's not already on, consider :set incsearch.
This will highlight matches while you type your pattern.
If the highlight goes away, you know exactly where you mistyped.

Thank you ! As you can probably guess, regex are... not my strongest area of expertise :)

I can only repeat: :help pattern
